# Rails Custom Model Functions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm in a databases course and the instructor wants us to develop an e-commerce app. She said we can use any framework we like, and now that we're halfway through the semester she decided that Rails does too much and wants me to explicitly write my SQL queries.

So, what I'd like to do is to write my own functions and add them to the models to essentially duplicate already existing functionality (but with SQL that I wrote myself).

So the questions then become:

1. How do I execute manually created queries inside the model?
2. How do I stuff the results into an empty object that I can then return and work with inside the view?

Also, I'm aware of what terrible practice this is, I just don't want to start all over in PHP at this point.

Comment: I'm sorry but almost every single framework has some sort of ORM nowadays - look at Doctrine for example. ActiveRecord doesn't even do a good job at hiding SQL - you can write SQL as part of your conditions/group/join options.

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't even **try** to hide SQL. Read what David Heinemeier Hansson, the creator of Rails, says on page 315 of the [Agile Web Development with Rails book](http://event2011.googlecode.com/files/Agile_Web.pdf): "[Active Record] was built on the notion that SQL is neither dirty nor bad, just verbose in the trivial cases. The focus is on removing the need to deal with the verbosity in those trivial cases (writing a 10-attribute insert by hand will leave any programmer tired) but keeping the expressiveness around for the hard queries—the type SQL was created to deal with elegantly."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you should know 2-3 really necessary methods, to use it.
(assume we have at least 2 models, Order and User(customer for order))
For example, just to run query on your database use this:

```
Order.connection.execute("DELETE FROM orders WHERE id = '2')
```

to get number of objects from your database, the best way is use method "count_by_sql", it's scalable. I'm using it in my projects, where table has over 500 thousands records. All work to count application gives to database, and it did it much more efficient than app.

```
Order.count_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.user_id) FROM orders o")
```

this query gets number of all uniq users who has an order. we can "JOIN ON" tables, order results using "ORDER BY" and group results.

and the most often use method: find_by_sql

```
Order.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM orders")
```

it returns to you an array with ruby objects.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have a purchase

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord:Base
    def Purchase.find(id)
        Purchase.find_by_sql(["Select * from purchases where id=?", id])
    end  
end
```

Maybe you want the products for a particular purchase.  You can manually define the purchased_items in your Purchase model.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord:Base
    def purchased_items
        PurchasedItem.find_by_sql(["Select * from purchased_items where purchase_id=?",self.id])
    end
end
```

So for example, in your controller where you now want to get the purchased items for a particular purchase you can now do this

```
@purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
@purchased_items = @purchase.purchased_items
```

If you need a more raw connection to the database, you can look into ActiveRecord:Base.connection.execute(sql)